# CM7.2 Viber installing problem

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, installation, htc-wildfire-s

I'm on HTC Wildfire S

With my stock ROM I can use all versions of Viber

But on CM7.2 I can't install newer version than 2.0.x.xxxxxx (I didn't try every version, but the 2.2. and 2.1. installing exit with the app didn't get installed message.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

This is a member of the Viber R&D Team.

Viber is not fully compatible with custom ROMs yet.. :/ 
However, please try to download from the following link:

[Viber Knowledgebase](http://helpme.viber.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/100/0/cant-download-from-android-market)

Let us know if the issue persists. :)

Comment: Please **do not** use URL shorteners here. They are unnecessary and are too often a vector for malicious sites/software.